# How to open gstreamer stream using opencv in python

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer

The following code successfully shows the mp4 video on the screen using only gstreamer

```
from threading import Thread
import time 
import gi
import cv2 
import numpy as np

gi.require_version("Gst", "1.0")
gi.require_version("GstApp", "1.0")

from gi.repository import Gst, GLib, GstApp

_ = GstApp


Gst.init()

main_loop = GLib.MainLoop()
thread = Thread(target=main_loop.run)
thread.start()


# pipeline = Gst.parse_launch("filesrc location = /home/user/Downloads/video.mp4 ! decodebin ! videoconvert !  appsink name=sink")
# appsink = pipeline.get_by_name("sink")

pipeline = Gst.parse_launch("filesrc location = /home/user/Downloads/video-trim.mp4 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink")

pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

try: 
    while True:
        time.sleep(.1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass


pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
main_loop.quit()
thread.join()
```

I would like to open and process each frame in opencv. More specifically, how can I use `cv2.VideoCapture()` to process the gstreamer sink? It is my understanding that `cv2.VideoCapture()` takes the whole gstreamer pipeline as the argument, however if I am running the pipeline using `Gst.parse_launch("filesrc location = /home/owner/Downloads/video-trim.mp4 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink")`, how can that interact with opencv?

Comment: `cap = cv2.VideoCapture("filesrc ...... ! appsink")` and use `cap` as usual

Comment: Unfortunately `cap.read()` does not get a frame using this approach. ret is never true when I run `ret, frame = cap.read()`. Im reading the cap right underneath the `pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)`, is this right?

Comment: Have you checked if your opencv is compiled with gstreamer enabled?  Have you changed your autovideosink to appsink?  Did you check cap.is_opened() if it is true?